# Multiple conditionally count in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to count thous cells which have **status=Done** and **Date = Jun 2022** in google sheet. Here I made a formula but not getting proper count value

```
=COUNTIFS(J1:J20,"Done*",L8:L200,(ArrayFormula(month(L1:L20)),(MONTH(TODAY())-1)))
```

[Here is data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zeEP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A,"Done",B2:B,">=" & DATE(2022,6,1),B2:B,"<=" & EOMONTH(DATE(2022,6,1),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but 4-Jun-2021 won't consider

Comment: Because you said `Jun 2022`.  If you count any `June` then try `=ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS(A2:A,"Done",Month(B2:B),6))`.